# Flickering primary tags on meta

Tags: bug, design

Chrome on OSX here.

No better way to explain this than steps to recreate:

- Start the ask question form on Meta
- Go to add a tag (focus the tag box). The primary tags will appear without any input.
- Mouse over one of the tags.

They flicker, and only do it if no input is in the box.

Comment: I don't see it with Firefox (38.3.0) on Windows.